# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null (using redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, null, react-redux

So I have the following method, which accepts an object 'x'. The 'x' object has a property called 'id'. I'm able to log the id in line **4**, but not in line **5**.

```
onOpenDeleteServiceModal=(x)=> {
    this.props.setReduxShowDeleteServiceModal(true);
    this.props.setReduxTargetedService(x); //save the object to reducer (using mapDispatchToProps)
    console.log(x.id); //works fine
    console.log(this.props.getReduxTargetedService.id); //error here
}
```

In line **3** I dispatch the object to my reducer and save it there (using redux), then in line **5** I try to log the objects id from the reducer, but I get *'TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null '*

mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    getReduxTargetedService: state.servicesState.targetedService,
})
```

mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
setReduxTargetedService: (x) =>
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_TARGETED_SERVICE', x}),
})
```

servicesReducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
targetedService: null,
};



function servicesReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_TARGETED_SERVICE': return { 
        ...state,
        targetedService: action.x
    }


    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: use ternary operator to check does `id` exist inside object `getReduxTargetedService`: `this.props.getReduxTargetedService && console.log(this.props.getReduxTargetedService.id)`.

Comment: Are you sure you properly save the X value in the reducer?
`console.log(x.id)` doesn't prove that this value is saved in state, because you reference local variable received as argument. I cannot tell for sure without code, but I suggest that you debug updating state. The problem might be there.
Additionally, name `getReduxTargetedService` suggests method, not a property.

Comment: show your reducer code which handles the setReduxTargetedService()

Comment: I don't know how to use the ternary operator, but I did this instead:


if(this.props.getReduxTargetedService){
    console.log(this.props.getReduxTargetedService.id);
}else{
    console.log("getReduxTargetedService.id doesen't exist");
}

And it's logging "getReduxTargetedService.id doesen't exist"

I'll add my reducer in a min

Comment: @sathishkumar just inserted my reducer

Comment: where is your `mapStateToProps`? can update your question with it?

Comment: Do you map state to props? You didn't attach it.

Comment: add mapStateToProps please?

Comment: @sathishkumar
just did

Comment: post your connect method?

Comment: export default compose(
    withFirebase,
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps,
    )
)(PricesForm);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 misconceptions here.

1 - redux store is updated asynchronously, which means that calling `this.props.getReduxTargetedService.id` right after dispatching the action won't work.

2 - that's not how react + redux work. Whenever you dispatch an action and update the store, you will only see the updated value after the component is re-rendered. That happens because the component is notified that some props has been updated. This is also valid depending on how you update the component state with `setState`, for example.

In your case, you can check the `this.props.getReduxTargetedService.id` value in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. You shoudl be able to see the new value

This is how react lifecycle looks like: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Here you have a more in-depth view about redux https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-redux/

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I'll need to read a bit more about the lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

`getReduxTargetedService` seems to be a method so you need to call it as such i.e. 
`this.props.getReduxTargetedService().id`

Comment: no, thats not the case - it's not a method. It's from 'mapStateToProps'

Answer (score 0):

I found an [article](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-redux-render-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-propertyname-of-null-c3292137ccf7) that helped me with the 'Cannot read property...' problem when using redux:

"**Don’t Return Null from Redux**..."

In my case, I just returned an **empty string** as default instead of **null** and the problem was fixed.